# Remove words in each row in a column of dataframe from another list of words in a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, pyspark

I want to subtract or remove the words in one dataframe from another dataframe in each row.

This is the main table/columns of a pyspark dataframe.

```
+----------+--------------------+
|  event_dt|           cust_text|
+----------+--------------------+
|2020-09-02|hi fine i want to go|
|2020-09-02|i need  a line hold |
|2020-09-02|i have the  60 packs|
|2020-09-02|hello want you teach|
```

Below is another pyspark dataframe. The words in this dataframe needs to be removed from the above main table in column `cust_text` wherever the words occur in each row. For example, 'want' will be removed from every row wherever it shows up in 1st dataframe.

```
+-------+
|column1|
+-------+
|   want|
|because|
|   need|
|  hello|
|      a|
|   have|
|     go|
+-------+
```

This can be done in pyspark or pandas. I have tried googling the solution using Python, Pyspark, pandas, but still not able to remove the words from the main table based on a single column table.

The result should look like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|  event_dt|           cust_text|
+----------+--------------------+
|2020-09-02|hi fine i to        |
|2020-09-02|i line hold         |
|2020-09-02|i the 60 packs      |
|2020-09-02|you teach           |
+----------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove just the word in the corresponding line of df2, you could do that as follows, but it will probably be slow for large data sets, because it only can partially can use fast C implementations:

```
# define your helper function to remove the string
def remove_string(ser_row):
    return ser_row['cust_text'].replace(ser_row['remove'], '')

# create a temporary column with the string to remove in the first dataframe
df1['remove']= df2['column1']
df1= df1.apply(remove_string, axis='columns')
# drop the temporary column afterwards
df1.drop(columns=['remove'], inplace=True)
```

The result looks like:

```
Out[145]: 
0        hi fine i  to go
1    i need   lines hold 
2    i have the  60 packs
3           can you teach
dtype: object
```

If however, you want to remove all words in your df2 column from **every** column, you need to do it differntly. Unfortunately `str.replace` does not help here with regular strings, unless you want to call it for every line in your second dataframe.
So if your second dataframe is not too large, you can create a regular expression to make use of `str.replace`.

```
import re
replace=re.compile(r'\b(' + ('|'.join(df2['column1'])) + r')\b')
df1['cust_text'].str.replace(replace, '')
```

The output is:

```
Out[184]: 
0      hi fine i  to 
1    i    lines hold 
2    i  the  60 packs
3       can you teach
Name: cust_text, dtype: object
```

If you don't like the repeated spaces, that remain, you can just perform something like:

```
df1['cust_text'].str.replace(replace, '').str.replace(re.compile('\s{2,}'), ' ')
```

Addition: what, if not only the text without the words is relevant, but the words themselves as well. How can we get the words, which were replaced. Here is one attempt, which would work, if one character can be identified, which will not appear in the text. Let's assume this character is a `@`, then you could do (on the original column value without replacement):

```
# enclose each keywords in @
ser_matched= df1['cust_text'].replace({replace: r'@\1@'}, regex=True)
# now remove the rest of the line, which is unmatched
# this is the part of the string after the last occurance
# of a @
ser_matched= ser_matched.replace({r'^(.*)@.*$': r'\1', '^@': ''}, regex=True)
# and if you like your keywords to be in a list, rather than a string
# you can split the string at last
ser_matched.str.split(r'@+')
```

Comment: 2nd dataframe(df2) has go which needs to be removed from 1st dataframe(df1). In your Output, i see 'go' is not removed from 1st dataframe.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. I thought, the lines in your second dataframe correspond to the lines in your first dataframe and that you just want to remove the string that belongs to the same line. Are you from india btw?

Comment: no.
I think I could not explain well. This was my first post to ask anything

Comment: No problem, I think I have a solution. Just a moment.

Comment: One last thing, I want to add 'event_dt' column back in the results with the respective row (as it was)

Comment: I think I found the way to add the original column back to the results based on your code.

import re

def remove_bogus_word(x, df2):
    replace=re.compile(r'\b(' + ('|'.join(df2['column1'])) + r')\b')
    return x.str.replace(replace, '').str.replace(re.compile('\s{2,}'), ' ')

df = df1.apply(lambda x: remove_bogus_word(x, df2))
df.head()

Comment: The code above `df1['cust_text'].str.replace(replace, '')` just creates a series. Don't you just need to assign it to a new column to have the desired result? Maybe I'm not getting you right. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I want the df1(main table) as is with the removals of the words based on df2(2nd table).

Comment: Ah I see, you want the "diff"?  I think, then you need to program a function and use map, which you have to call twice, or loop over the dataframe.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to find out how to do that?

Comment: I have a very specific solution, which assumes you can identify a character, which will not appear in your text. I'll add it above.

Answer (score 0):

This solution would be specific to pandas. If I understand your challenge correctly, you want to remove all words from column `cust_text` that occur in `column1` of the second DataFrame. Lets give the corresponding DataFrames the names: `df1` and `df2`. This is how you would do this:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    sentence = df1.loc[i, "cust_text"]
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        delete_word = df2.loc[j, "column1"]
        if delete_word in sentence:
            sentence = sentence.replace(delete_word, "")
    df1.loc[i, "cust_text"] = sentence
```

I have assigned variables to certain data points in these dataframes (`sentence` and `delete_word`), but that is just for the sake of understanding. You can easily condense this code to a few lines shorter by not doing that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.
How can you define the length of the dataframe?---> for i in range(len(df1)):    df1 has 2 columns - event_dt, cust_text.

Comment: A DataFrame technically should always have the same number of rows, regardless of how many columns it has. Think of it 1 row as 1 item, which contains information about all the features (aka columns) in the dataframe. That said, you can access the length of any dataframe (i.e. the number of rows) through `len(dataframe)`. This is a built-in python function.